# Why doesn't display parent also display children?

Tags: javascript, css, display

I'm trying to create a form with some display: block/none system with select field, but I've got a weird behaviour:

When I display block a div that I had display none before, the children of this div don't take the display block but keep the display none. I've tried this with visibility option but same behaviour.

How can I correct it ? Is that a normal behaviour ?

Many thanks !

```
<div class="row row-no-gutter-x mt-2">
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 form-floating pe-lg-1">
                    <select class="form-select" name="even_type" required>
                        @foreach($even_types as $type)
                            @if ($type->id == 1)                                        
                                <option value="{{ $type->id }}" selected>{{ $type->nom }}</option>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    </select>    
                    <label for="even_type">Type d'évenement <span class="text-danger-main">*</span></label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-12 form-floating ps-lg-1 mt-2 mt-lg-0">
                    <select class="form-select" name="ville" onchange="changeMdn(this.value)" required>                                     
                        <option value="angers" selected>Angers</option>
                        <option value="boulogne">Boulogne-Billancourt</option>
                        <option value="defense">La Défense</option>
                        <option value="lorient">Lorient</option>
                        <option value="nantes">Nantes</option>
                        <option value="rouen">Rouen</option>
                    </select>    
                    <label for="ville">Type d'évenement <span class="text-danger-main">*</span></label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id="mdnSpaces">
                <div id="angersSpaces" style="display: block;">
                    angers
                    <div class="form-floating mt-2">
                        <select class="form-select" name="ville" onchange="changeAngersMdn(this.value)" required>                                     
                            <option value="ralliment" selected>Place du Ralliement</option>
                            <option value="lenepveu">Rue Lenepveu</option>
                            <option value="pilori">Place du Pilori</option>
                        </select>    
                        <label for="ville">Type d'évenement <span class="text-danger-main">*</span></label>
                    </div>
                    <div id="angersEmplacement">
                        <div id="angersSpacesralliment">
                            {{ Form::open(['route' => 'mdn.angers.ralliement.create']) }}
                                ralliment
                            {{ Form::close() }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="angersSpaceslenepveu" style="display: none;">
                            {{ Form::open(['route' => 'mdn.angers.lenepveu.create']) }}
                                lenepveu
                            {{ Form::close() }}
                        </div>
                        <div id="angersSpacespilori" style="display: none;">
                            {{ Form::open(['route' => 'mdn.angers.pilori.create']) }}
                                pilori
                            {{ Form::close() }}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div id="boulogneSpaces" style="display: none;">
                    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'mdn.boulogne.create', 'id' => 'boulogneMdnForm']) }}
                        boulogne
                    {{ Form::close() }}
                </div>
                <div id="defenseSpaces" style="display: none;">
                    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'mdn.defense.event.create', 'id' => 'defenseMdnForm']) }}
                        defense
                    {{ Form::close() }}
                </div>
                <div id="lorientSpaces" style="display: none;">
                    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'mdn.lorient.create', 'id' => 'lorientMdnForm']) }}
                        lorient
                    {{ Form::close() }}
                </div>
                <div id="nantesSpaces" style="display: none;">
                    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'mdn.nantes.event.create', 'id' => 'nantesMdnForm']) }}
                        nantes
                    {{ Form::close() }}
                </div>
                <div id="rouenSpaces" style="display: none;">
                    {{ Form::open(['route' => 'mdn.rouen.event.create', 'id' => 'rouenMdnForm']) }}
                        rouen
                    {{ Form::close() }}
                </div>
            </div>

function changeAngersMdn(emplacement){
    const angersEmplacement = document.getElementById('angersEmplacement').getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var empl of angersEmplacement){
        if(empl.id == 'angersSpaces'+emplacement){
            empl.style.display = "block";  
        }else{
            empl.style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
}

function changeMdn(ville){
    const mdns = document.getElementById('mdnSpaces').getElementsByTagName("div");
    for(var mdn of mdns){
        if(mdn.id == ville+'Spaces'){
            mdn.style.display = "block";       
        }else{
            mdn.style.display = "none"; 
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What templating engine/library are you using?

Comment: i'm usig laravel 7 with BS 5.2.

Comment: Okay, thanks. the {{ moustache }} notation reminded me of some other frameworks but not quite.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need explicit `display:none` on the children if they are in the DOM tree correctly below their parent, just hide and toggle the parent.

```js
let parents = document.getElementsByClassName('parent');
for(let parent of parents){
  parent.onclick = (ev) => {
    if (ev.target.style.display === "none") {
      ev.target.style.display = "block";
    } else {
      ev.target.style.display = "none";
    }
  }
}

let show = document.getElementById('show');
show.onclick = () => {
  for(let parent of parents){
    parent.style.display = "block";
  }
};
```

```css
.parent {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.child {
  background-color: blue;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
}

#show {
  width: 100px;
  background-color: green;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<div class='parent'>
  click me to hide
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>
  click me to hide
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
<div class='parent'>
  click me to hide
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
  <div class='child'></div>
</div>
<div id='show'>show all</div>
```

Comment: Hello, many thanks for your answer. I've tried to hide in my css file the DOM element in need, but the problem still the same.

Comment: The children should not have the `display` attribute set at all and just get hidden based on parent. It is IMPOSSIBLE for the problem to be the same if you removed the attribute from the child elements.

Answer (score 0):

I've find what's wrong :
I was selecting all div inside parent, that mean it select all div, no matter the level of child the div is. Just change by .getElementByClassName and use a class for select only div i wanted.